# If $A$ is an independent $RV$, and Var$[A+A]$ $= $Var$[A]$ + Var$[A] + 2$Cov$[A,A]$. Then Cov$[A,A]$ = Var$[A] = 0$, is this a flaw in logic?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $A$ is an independent $RV$. Then we know that
Var$[A+A] = $Var$[A] + $Var$[A]$

This also means that 
Cov$[A,A] = 0$ and likewise Cov$[A,A] = $Var$[A] = 0$.

So Var$[A+A] = 0 + 0 + 0$.

This does not seem right to me, can someone point out my flaw in logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying $A$ is an independent random variable if you mean that $A$ is independent of itself, then all the equalities you have written are correct. In this case $A$ is necessarily a constant random variable so its variance and covariance with itself are both $0$.

Comment: Thanks makes sense